# yargs says nested arguments provided via JSON are "missing"

Tags: javascript, node.js, yargs

Using yargs 16.2.0, I've defined some nested options and provided them via a config file, but yargs still claims that they are missing:

**yargs**

```
yargs
  .command('do-stuff', 'Does some neat stuff.', o => o
    .option('test.something', {
      type: 'string',
      demandOption: true,
      requiresArg: true,
    })
  )
  .strict()
  .demandCommand()
  .config('env')
  .help()
  .argv;
```

**config.json**

```
{
  "test": {
    "something": "blah"
  }
}
```

Executed via ...

```
> node index.js -- do-stuff --env config.json

index.js do-stu

Does some neat stuff.

Options:
  --version         Show version number                                [boolean]
  --env             Path to the environment config JSON from which to load
                    arguments.
  --help            Show help                                          [boolean]
  --test.something                                           [string] [required]

Missing required argument: test.something
```

I then edited `node_modules/yargs-parser/build/index.cjs` ([original here](https://github.com/yargs/yargs-parser/blob/master/lib/yargs-parser.ts#L671)) and added a line to log out `argv` after parsing the config JSON:

```
setConfigObject(config);            // line 630, existing
console.log(JSON.stringify(argv));  // added for debugging
```

The resulting output:

```
{
    "_": ["do-stuff"],
    "env": "config.json",
    "test":
    {
        "something": "blah"
    }
}
```

I made the same change in `node_modules/yargs/build/index.cjs`, after line 1472 (just before the "Missing required arguments" message is displayed, and the JSON output still includes the `test.something` argument.

---

So, why is yargs claiming that my argument(s) were not supplied, when even `argv` shows that they were?

Comment: Looking into the code some more, this is likely just a bug or unsupported use case.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug or unsupported use case in yargs: https://github.com/yargs/yargs/issues/1782